# Mass flow rate from pierced pressurised cylinder

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow

I am looking to determine the relative mass flow rate resulting from a puncture in a high-pressure cylinder for hydrogen and natural gas:

[image]

Note that the Outside Pressure (P2) is not necessarily atmospheric pressure.

I am struggling to get my head around the problem. The flow rate will reduce over time I think since the pressure in the cylinder (P1) will decrease. What I am really after is the relative mass flow rate between the two gases for a give P1 and P2 at a given time.

I also assume the process to be adiabatic, with no heat being transferred through the cylinder walls.

I found a few solutions out there for incompressible fluid but nothing I could understand for compressible gases.

Thanks

Comment: Google "discharge coefficient."

Answer (score -1):

Let:

- $n(t)$ the instantaneous number of moles of gas inside the cylinder, $n_0$ the initial number of moles
- $P(t)$ the instantaneous pressure of gas inside the cylinder
- $P_0$ the initial pressure inside the cylinder, $P_2$ the pressure outside the cylinder

We assume reasonably, with $\alpha$ a coefficient:

$$\frac{\text{d}n(t)}{\text{d}t}=-\alpha [P(t)-P_2]$$

(note that indeed $\frac{\text{d}n(t)}{\text{d}t}<0$, hence the minus sign)

Ideal gas law:
$$PV=nRT$$
In case of an **isothermal** isochoric process:
$$\frac{P(t)}{P_0}=\frac{n(t)}{n_0}$$
Derive both sides wrt time:
$$\frac{\text{d}n(t)}{\text{d}t}=\frac{n_0}{P_0}\frac{\text{d}P(t)}{\text{d}t}$$

Insert into top equation:
$$\frac{n_0}{P_0}\frac{\text{d}P(t)}{\text{d}t}=-\alpha [P(t)-P_2]$$
Rearrange and integrate:
$$\frac{\text{d}P}{P-P_2}=-\frac{\alpha P_0}{n_0}\text{d}t$$
$$\ln\Big[\frac{P_e-P_2}{P_0-P_2}\Big]=-\frac{\alpha P_0}{n_0}\Delta t$$

where $P_e$ is the end-pressure inside the cylinder.

**So both the pressure and the molar flow decay exponentially in time.**

But this is the **isothermal** case. The adiabatic one is much more complex.

The classic adiabatic formula:

$$PV^{\gamma}=\text{constant}$$

obviously doesn't apply here. That's because it's an open system.

I believe we need to use the work done by the escaping gas on the environment: the escaping gas pushes the surrounding gas out of the way and thus performs work on it. But I can't really see a way forward.